# What are all the possible tags that can be used inside the web.xml concerning a Java EE project?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

Concerning `Java EE` with `Tomcat` we know that there is the `web.xml` file to be used and edited. I know that there are the tags `<web-app>`, `<servlet>`, `<servlet-mapping>` that can be written inside the web.xml file. But I want to know are there other tags that can be used ? Where can we learn all the possible tags we can put in the web.xml file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brief: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html

XSD: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd

Java Servlet 2.5 Specification: 
http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr154/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Download the Java Servlet Specification in the version of choice - it will probably be 2.4, 2.5 or 3.0, depending on your application server.